I have duplicated commits after pull request, How can I get rid of this?
We're developing a web application with my friends. Whenever we commit into this repo, GitHub always duplicate commits. I don't want this to happen and I don't even know this is true.
I want to explain how we do it:

Clone original repo with  git clone original-repo.git
Create a new branch for a feature, update, fix etc. Let's call this branch a navbar
Commit these changes and publish a navbar branch
Create a pull request, admin merges this pull request into the main and deletes navbar branch

When I check commit history, there is duplicated commits and one of them has verified tag. What do we do wrong? Here is a screen shot for it:

For information, we used to fork the original repo and commit but that way we have to update original repo and I see a lot of update messages. That's why we're not doing that way any more.
Edıt: here is output of git log --oneline --graph
img
Why there is 2 "update: updated navbar social and added href functionality" I commited only 1 time and merged it. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to contribute a project?

Are you squash-merging when you merge a PR?

I think that it's also possible to do a "merge"with rebase on providers.... that might also explain it.

You didn't do anything "wrong".  It looks like your merge strategy is rebasing and re-writing commits. It's nothing to worry about; eventually a garbage collector will (probably) clean up the dangling refs.  The image is not enough information to really see what's happening.  It would help to give the output of git log --oneline --graph or similar, or find a good graphical representation of the commit tree that shows more than the image you've provided.

Note that "deletes navbar branch" may not be doing what you think it is doing.  git is pretty conservative about actually deleting data.  When the branch is "deleted", none of the commits are actually purged from the repository.  That won't happen until a garbage collection cycle actually deletes the dangling ref which may not hapen for weeks, or months, or never.

The image you provided does not give any relational information. Can you instead replace it with a screenshot from gitk --all?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

From your git log, it looks like the later commit is the merge commit that merges your pull request into main.
You can see this because it has lines connecting it to both ecec914 and 29f6bdf.
If you open a PR with only one commit, GitHub defaults to using the commit message as the PR description, and the PR description forms the commit message for the merge commit when you merge the PR.
The later commit is verified because it is a commit made by GitHub, and they sign their commits with the GitHub commit key.

GitHub will automatically use GPG to sign commits you make using the web interface. Commits signed by GitHub will have a verified status.

source
If you inspect the contents of the commits with git show -v <ref>, you should see that the first commit contains the changes and the second commit is empty (because its purpose is to be a merge commit that combines two histories that had diverged).
If you want to avoid these merge commits in the future you need to change how you merge pull requests.
One option is to merge to the main branch using git merge --ff-only <branch name> and then push. GitHub will automatically close the PR if it detects that you have merged it this way. This will only merge if you can fast-forward without creating a merge commit.
If you want/need to do it from the GitHub UI you can use the drop-down on the Merge pull request button and select Rebase and merge which will rebase your commits on top of main and then fast-forward.
Note that if you're signing your commits, Rebase and merge might remove your signature and replace it with GitHub's.


Thank you for your interest. What can I do to prevent this situation? I don't want to see duplicated commit messages in commit history.

@sevro49 Don't use Github to merge fast-forwardable history.

I've updated the answer with information on how to avoid the duplicated commit

If this solved your problem, please mark it as the answer :)

Remove the whole repo, check it our fresh, and it works
